# Parent and child process control

Tags: c, process

I'm not sure about the title so please correct it if you know a better one.

I'm doing a simple "server" program in C and I'm using a child process just to read "exit" and close the "server" without blocking the main process.

How can I use the exit signal from the child to exit a "loop" in the parent process?

Parent process:

```
while(<child is not over>)
{
   //process
}
exit...
```

Child process:

```
do{
  scanf("%s", op);
} while(strcmp(op, EXIT_OPTION) != 0);

exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

I could use `wait` or `waitpid` but I don't want the parent to block, just to "check" it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`waitpid` has a non-blocking mode. If you pass `WNOHANG` as the third argument of `waitpid`, it will return immediately. You can check the return value and/or the status(returned by the second argument of `waitpid`) to check whether the child has exited. By default, `waitpid` waits only for terminated children, and it returns the pid of the child. If no children has changed state, it returns 0.

For more information, you can check the manual page of `waitpid`.

Comment: I already tested and it works. Just with a correction on the code, it's .. == 0 and not ... != 0.

Thank you!

Comment: My bad @Matthias . Done!